# how can i sort multidimensional array in php by particular my_id

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

This is my array code sample which i need to sort without built in functions, i tried with 2 loops but it looks like i am not getting proper output for this program, please check and give me possible solutions if you have..

```
$my_array = array(
    '51171#2'  => array(
       'my_id'  => 51171,
       'variation_id' => 2,
    ),
    '143516#2' => array(
       'my_id'  => 143516,
       'variation_id' => 2,
    ),
    '396346#2' => array(
       'my_id'  => 396346,
       'variation_id' => 2,
    ),
    '143516#1' => array(
       'my_id'  => 143516,
       'variation_id' => 1,
    ),
    '396344#2' => array(
       'my_id'  => 396344,
       'variation_id' => 2,
    ),
    '396346#1' => array(
       'my_id'  => 396346,
       'variation_id' => 1,
    ),
    '396344#1' => array(
       'my_id'  => 396344,
       'variation_id' => 1,
    ),
  );
```

**above is my sample array, so here i want to sort by my_id and without using php built in functions. And i want output like this:-**

```
$output_arr = array(
  '143516#2' => array(
     'my_id'  => 143516,
     'variation_id' => 2,
  ),
  '143516#1' => array(
     'my_id'  => 143516,
     'variation_id' => 1,
  ),
  '396344#2' => array(
     'my_id'  => 396344,
     'variation_id' => 2,
  ),
  '396344#1' => array(
     'my_id'  => 396344,
     'variation_id' => 1,
  ),
  '396346#2' => array(
     'my_id'  => 396346,
     'variation_id' => 2,
  ),
  '396346#1' => array(
     'my_id'  => 396346,
     'variation_id' => 1,
  ),
  '51171#2'  => array(
     'my_id'  => 51171,
     'variation_id' => 2,
  ),
);
```

**So i try code :-**

```
  $result = [];
foreach($my_array as $key => $source){   
    foreach($my_array as $key1 => $source1){
        if(($source['my_id'] < $source1['my_id']))
        {        
              $result[$key1]= $source1;      
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

**Output :-**

```
Array
(
    [143516#2] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 143516
            [variation_id] => 2
        )

    [396346#2] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 396346
            [variation_id] => 2
        )

    [143516#1] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 143516
            [variation_id] => 1
        )

    [396344#2] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 396344
            [variation_id] => 2
        )

    [396346#1] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 396346
            [variation_id] => 1
        )

    [396344#1] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 396344
            [variation_id] => 1
        )
)
```

but this is not correct output, please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Why do you need to sort without built in functions? Seems a strange constrain.

Comment: @KoalaYeung This might be a school assignment.

Comment: Why `my_id` with value `51171` will come at the end?

Comment: Nice_dev because this is lesser than all

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution(s).

**With `uasort()`:**

```php
$my_array = array(
  '51171#2'  => array(
     'my_id'  => 51171,
     'variation_id' => 2,
  ),
  '143516#2' => array(
     'my_id'  => 143516,
     'variation_id' => 2,
  ),
  '396346#2' => array(
     'my_id'  => 396346,
     'variation_id' => 2,
  ),
  '143516#1' => array(
     'my_id'  => 143516,
     'variation_id' => 1,
  ),
  '396344#2' => array(
     'my_id'  => 396344,
     'variation_id' => 2,
  ),
  '396346#1' => array(
     'my_id'  => 396346,
     'variation_id' => 1,
  ),
  '396344#1' => array(
     'my_id'  => 396344,
     'variation_id' => 1,
  ),
);
function sortArr($x, $y){
    $xid = $x['my_id'];
    $yid = $y['my_id'];
    if ((int)((String)$xid)[0] != (int)((String)$yid)[0]){
      return (int)((String)$xid)[0] < (int)((String)$yid)[0] ? -1 : 1;
    }else if ($xid != $yid){
      return $xid < $yid ? -1 : 1;
    }else{
      return $x['variation_id'] < $y['variation_id'] ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
uasort($my_array, "sortArr");
print_r($my_array);
```

**Without`uasort()`:**

```php
function sortArr($x, $y){
    $xid = $x['my_id'];
    $yid = $y['my_id'];
    if ((int)((String)$xid)[0] != (int)((String)$yid)[0]){
      return (int)((String)$xid)[0] < (int)((String)$yid)[0] ? -1 : 1;
    }else if ($xid != $yid){
      return $xid < $yid ? -1 : 1;
    }else{
      return $x['variation_id'] < $y['variation_id'] ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
$tempres = $result = [];
foreach($my_array as $key => $value){
  $i = 0;
  foreach($tempres as $elem){
    if (sortArr($my_array[$key], $elem) < 0) break;
    $i++;
  }
  array_splice($tempres, $i, 0, array($key => $my_array[$key]));
}
foreach($tempres as $elem){
  $result[array_search($elem, $my_array)] = $elem;
}
print_r($result);
```

Very long, so the code can probably be cleaned up a bit more. Hope that's what you were looking for :)

Comment: Great buddy just checked working fine , but why uasort

Comment: _sort by my_id and without using php built in functions_ And you are using `uasort()`

Comment: @nice_dev yes, it sorts by `my_id` (see the `sortArr` function), and I know I'm using `uasort()`.

Comment: Also, I use `uasort` because I thought it doesn't count (requires making your own function). But anyways I'll try not using it :)

Comment: Alright, added solution without `uasort()` (finally). Hope it works!